# How to retrieve plain text from a formatted website to use in UIWebView

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

Not sure if what I want to do is possible, but what I am hoping to do is somehow gather certain pieces of text from a website, remove the header, footer, background, all formatting, and place it into my application in a scrollview or something similar...

I'll give you an example... Imagine I was making wikipedia's iPhone app, I want to download the information about the wiki on dogs, without the header, side bars etc, just the text. How would I go about doing this?

I understand that for this I have not provided any example code or what I've tried or started, but that's just because in this case I'm lost! That doesn't mean I want full chunks of code either. Any help will do. If this doesn't work, I will just have to make a 'mobile optimised' version of the webpages I want to include in my app.

Thanks

(Edit: the term I was trying to use was 'strip the web page of its HTML coding')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be going about this the wrong way, or perhaps even asking the wrong question.

Does the target website have an API or datafeed of some kind? 
Can you get the information you need in JSON or XML format directly from the site?

I think you've misunderstood the technology. HTML is merely the framwork on which the formatting and data is hung.

Parsing the HTML page seems like an awfully big headache, I doubt you'll ever be able to get it to work, because almost all sites these days are partially or wholly generated on the server side, the page is only the result.

Some sites hide the information in memory and others get it dynamically through ajax for example, which means that simply trying to get the data by parsing the HTML will get zero data.

Another issue you should be aware of though, is that simply copying the data from generated websites may open yourself up to copyright issues.

Comment: I am making my application for someone, but I thought I'd try to get things working before bugging them and having them make a mobile version o a few pages, which I will probably end up doing now, so copyright isn't an issue.

Comment: @AndreC have you tried just copy pasting the HTML only. That way you get a HTML file without the link to the CSS file, then all you have to do is view the HTML file (stored locally) in your browser and normally all you see is the pure text. You can then copy past that into a text editor. This wouldn't take long but it would be less time than writing code to parse the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the html code and search for the part that you want and "throw" away the part that you do not need. This is more or less like bruteforcing and the code of the website should not change otherwise you are screwed. So you have to write the parser by hand with this method. But maybe there is a atom or rss feed and you can parse this one. This will be much more easier and you are not depending on the website layout because the rss/atom feed is just about the data. For parsing rss you could try out `NSXMLParser`.
And then you have to make a valid html page out of the data and present it in the `UIWebView`